# How to replicate image highlighting effect from Gmail composer using CSS or SVG filter effect?

Tags: css, svg, sass

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Can this be done with pure CSS? I've tried to determine how Gmail does this, but their obfuscation has gotten quite good.

If this can't be doen with CSS alone, would SVG filters be an appropriate method to replicate this?

Comment: If you provide a markup/CSS sample it would be possible to suggest a proper answer

Comment: It's an image... If you know the answer then what I have provided is enough.

Comment: Well, since an image can be rendered (markup wise) in more than one way, the markup matters, and also its parent markup together with both their CSS might give additional possibilities to solve what you ask. The given answer assume an `img`, which can be altered with a SVG matrix or a combination of the built-in one's. I try to not assume _what_, instead ask, and with that being able to give a proper answer. And if you don't want to provide that, you limit the options to solve your issue, but of course, it is your choice.

Comment: Isn't that the browsers default text/image selection style? When I compare the email compose window with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kmxwp7tz/ they behave exactly the same in Chrome (Mac)

Comment: @Turnip you're correct. It's the default behavior. I was trying to replicate it in Electron so it looks like I'm not even asking the right question. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The image tinting can be done easily and so can the text inversion. But as far as I can figure - it's hard to combine the image tinting and the text inversion in a single filter. Here is the image tinting FWIW:

```css
img:hover {
  filter: url(#bluetone);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="bluetone">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 
                                             0 0 0 0 0 
                                             1 1 1 0 0
                                             0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/32648/Sample%20Image.PNG">
```

You can tweak the filter so it's the exact tint that you want - just make sure that the pattern you're using for the filter is

```
x x x 0 0 
y y y 0 0 
z z z 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll look into what can be done with this and accept it as an answer if it's workable.